# Create Dynamic IDs to rotate images on page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to rotate every image on a page, it works with only one image but since it needs all the IDs to be unique it only rotates the first one. 
I have to somehow dynamically increment the IDs as it finds on the page, here is what I have but no success.

```
  <script>
    $('#media').find('img').each(function(i) {

    var value = 0;
    // $("#image").rotate({
    // $(this).attr('id','#image' + i).rotate({
    $(this).attr('#image' + i).rotate({
        bind:
                {
                    click: function() {
                        value += 90;
                        // $(this).rotate({ animateTo:value})
                        $(this).rotate({animateTo: value});
                    }
                }
    });
})
</script>

<span id="media"><img src="image.jpg" alt="" title="" width="" height="" id="image" /></span>
<span id="media"><img src="photo.jpg" alt="" title="" width="" height="" id="image" /></span>
```

I am trying a different approach, by assigning an unique ID for the images already and then interacting over it, but something still doesn't work, here is what I have now:

```
  <script language="JavaScript">

  $(document.body).on('click','[id^=image_]',function(){

           var id = this.id.split("_").pop();

           var value = 0

           $('#image_' + id).rotate({

             bind:

            {
              click: function(){

                value +=90;

                $(this).rotate({ animateTo:value})

              }

             }

           });

          })
       </script>
```

And inside of the BODY tag the images:

```
<img src="image.jpg" alt="" title="" width="" height="" id="image_1233" /></span>
<img src="photo.jpg" alt="" title="" width="" height="" id="image_0322" /></span>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

What is this supposed to do? This looks like you are trying to get an *attribute* called "#image" + i = "#image1"?

```
$(this).attr('#image' + i)
```

---

Do you mean:

```
$(this).attr('id', 'image' + i)
```

Comment: I am trying to every time I see an image added to the page I can use or create an  unique ID so it can be rotated.

Comment: You should be able to do this with ab object reference without an ID. $(this) will refer to the currently selected image automatically.

Answer (score 1):

if you only bind a event (example "on click") you don't need to add a unique id. However (as Diodeus said) you use a incorrect selector, becose this line:

```
$(this).attr('#image'+ i)
```

return an value, not a elements collection. [Look here for jQuery docs](https://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr1) ;)

If you assign a ID (or another attribute) to the element use the from:

```
// $(this).attr( attribute, value )
$(this).attr( 'id', '#image'+ i )
```

Regards,

Kevin

Comment: What if I attach an unique number to the image ID as: ><img src="image.jpg" alt="" title="" width="" height="" id="image_0111" /> ><img src="image.jpg" alt="" title="" width="" height="" id="image_2234" /> and loop through it?

Answer (score 0):

When you want to bind an event to each image on a page which performs the rotation, you could do something like

```
var value = 0;

$('img').bind('click',function() {
  $(this).rotate({animateTo: value});
});
```

You do not need a unique id for each of the images. (as Kevin Lucich said)

Check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/7JBW5/ which rotates the images randomly.

---

### Update

http://jsfiddle.net/7JBW5/1/

When you only want to rotate some images, add a class to them.

```
<span><img class="rotatable" src="http://placehold.it/50x50" alt="" title="" width="" height="" /></span>
```

Then you can bind the event only to these

```
$('img.rotatable').bind('click',function() {
  value = Math.floor((Math.random()*360)+1);
  $(this).rotate({animateTo: value});
});
```

Comment: But if you don't have an ID all the images on the page will be under these conditions, right?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I made it to work, but thanks for trying helping me!

```
<head>
<script language="JavaScript">

$(function(){

  $('img[id^="image_"]').each(function(){
       var value = 0;
           $(this).rotate({

             bind:

            {
              click: function(){

                value +=90;

                $(this).rotate({ animateTo:value})
                //console.log(value);

              }

             }

           });

          });
         });


</script>
</head>
<body>
<img src="image.jpg" alt="" title="" width="" height="" id="image_1233" />
<img src="photo.jpg" alt="" title="" width="" height="" id="image_0322" />
</body>
```